# How reliable is the IMSDb as a source for (quotes to use as references for) answers on M&TV?

Tags: discussion

In [an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/146387/19561) over on SciFi.StackExchange, I've included a quote from a script on the Internet Movie Script Database, the IMSDb.

I've since used its script for *Inglorious Basterds* as a source [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/66728/9382), too. [Twice](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/66730/9382) now.

But how reliable is it? The scripts can be submitted by anyone, so it seems. Are they checked, or just uploaded to the site?

What's to stop me from writing a fictional discarded draft of *Star Wars* where Leia was *Han's* sister?

As such, can it be used as a reliable source to base answers on?